# What is the difference between FormGroup and FormArray? When to use what?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I have multiple dynamic `FormGroup`s in my code.

Also, some `FormGroup`s have a feature to add multiple `FormGroup`s/`FormControl`s.

So while creating `FormGroup` dynamically I have used `FormBuilder.group()` but for multiple groups, there is an array of data for which I want to create `FormControl`s.

How can I create dynamic `FormControl`s for this array of data objects?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: Briefly, FormGroup act as an object and FormArray, as an array of objects.

Comment: @Rafael, a FormArray can manage also a simple Array

Comment: Haven't seen that happening yet, @Eliseo, but if you have any example, would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Rafael, `myArray=[2,3]; myFormArray=new FormArray(myArray.map(x=>new FormControl(x)))`

Comment: But you see, you're casting it into a FormControl, which, in sum, is an object. So you're not really passing a simple array but a simple array that was casted into a list of FormControls.

Comment: So a FormArray contains FormGroups, and A FormGroup contains FormControls. Is the logic right? @Rafael

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think of Reactive Forms as forms around your data model. So a Reactive Form would correspond exactly to the way your data model is.

Consider this data-model for example:

```js
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Leanne Graham",
  username: "Bret",
  email: "Sincere@april.biz",
  isVerified: false,
  address: {
    street: "Kulas Light",
    suite: "Apt. 556",
    city: "Gwenborough",
    zipcode: "92998-3874",
  },
  phone: "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  website: "hildegard.org",
  posts: [[
    {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      body: "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto",
      commentIds: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, {
      userId: 1,
      id: 2,
      title: "qui est esse",
      body: "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla",
      commentIds: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }
  ]]
}
```

#### Now here's the over-all gist of what Reactive Form would be like for this data-model.

1. If the value of a property is an Object(like `address`), then we'll create a `FormGroup` for it.
2. If the value of a property is an Array(like `posts`), then we'll create a `FormArray` for it.
3. If the value of a property is a primitive(like `id`, `name`, `isVerified` etc), we'll create a FormControl for it.

That's all there is to it. It's all pretty straight-forward.

#### Now you might think:

> What will you create for `posts`?
>
> What will you create for `commentIds`?

So if you go back to the rules above:

> You'll create a `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s for `posts`.
>
> And you'll create a `FormArray` of `FormControl`s for `commentIds`.

This should answer your main question.

**PS:** We'll need more information to help you out with the exact code on how to do what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The answer seems to be extrapolating a lot from what the SO haven't said yet. The question is incomplete.